# LinkedIn access token api returns bad request error in c#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am using linked oauth 2 api to fetch the access token.But I am getting a 400 (BadRequest) response from that api.I am sharing the code below

```
NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
parameters.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
parameters.Add("code", Code);
parameters.Add("redirect_uri", RedirectURL);
parameters.Add("client_id", ClientId);
parameters.Add("client_secret", ClientSecret);


WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType]="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
var result = client.UploadValues("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken", parameters);
```

Could anyone help me to find what went wrong here. I am passing the correct values for all parameters, got `client_id`, `client_secret` from my application and the code I am getting from my initial authorization request.

I am not able to test this scenario in postman since the auth-token request depends on the code generated from the authorization step.

Comment: Is there a message in the response? Unless someone is very familiar with that API just showing code is not much help to diagnose a 400.

Comment: "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request" This is the response that I am getting.

Answer (score 1):

AuthorizationUrl must look like this

> https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=78y4rii84jcf43&state=E30980C1T666444z&redirect_uri=https://www.testWeb.com

Access Token Url will look like this,

> https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=AQTTP5DZ68JHRVO2_i9vpie8KBZ3gfgffhjfhjfhjfp88hf3szNauFkUpuvqfyKhjsmO7Bcps4JXUo1EWQay1q1q1MXKsajRWoZ4q-ofmTjJfknaYTk5SO5oHUgfhgfdsgfdgdfdgfsgdgdhgdhgddipkfTIzdkGUSWZkPYS1&client_id=78y4rii465rv084&redirect_uri=https://www.testweb.com&client_secret=1t56E7bLDl2fnVWh

And your Params are missing with

QUESTION_MARK (?) after https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken

your Grant type param must include grant_type=authorization_code 
than & param
than client_id=YourApiKey
than & param
than redirect_uri=YourRedirectUri
than &
than client_secret=YourSecretKey

Comment: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2
here you will get step by step guide

just to save your time
Use this Url in OnPostExecute after getting AccessToken 
getHttpRequestWithHeader

                String url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,industry,headline,positions,summary,picture-urls::(original),email-address)?format=json";

And in Header put ("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + accessToken)

Comment: I have used oath 2.0 but the code is in java, if you can understand java I will share

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth you are right, I didn't pay close enough attention. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: your url is wrong thats y u are getting bad request, and this genrates token which is than used in get request with header and in that api url has to passed 
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,industry,headline,positions,summary,picture-urls::(original),email-address)?format=json%22

Comment: I am getting these fields from this url after get http request with header
Fields from Linkedin Oath 2.0 (r_basicprofile & r_emailaddress)
1. Name
2. Email Address
3. Description
4. Designation
5. Company Name
6. Industry
7. Current Job Start Date
8. User Profile Pic Url